# Is it possible to show a function's name in Haskell (ghci)?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ghc

I know it is not possible to [show the function's body](https://wiki.haskell.org/Show_instance_for_functions) since Haskell carries out optimisations, but is it possible to somehow show it's *name*?

I would like something like

```
Prelude> f
[Function f]
```

similar to what other REPL's do (Python, javascript, etc.)

What I get with Haskell is

```
Prelude> f
<interactive>:2:1: error:
    • No instance for (Show (Integer -> Integer)) arising from a use of ‘print’ (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

which is not helpful in demonstrations.

Comment: btw: If you type `:i f` or `:t f` in prelude you get the name along with some more information about the function, might that help your cause?

Comment: That is literally something I would like to show, that doing ˋconst fˋ on ˋ5ˋ gives ˋfˋ

Comment: It would also break referential transparency. Since in Haskell there should be no functional difference between an expression and its evaluated result.

Comment: @LukeCollins For demonstration purposes you could use [lambdabot](https://wiki.haskell.org/Lambdabot) which has the `?src` command, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786372/how-can-i-view-the-definition-of-a-function-in-haskell-ghci).

Comment: Functions don't have names. They are *values*. Variables have names. What is the name of 5? There is none.

Comment: Even Python is doing something subtly different. Define a function `f`, then set `g = f`, then evaluate `g`. It still reports the name as `f`. Functions are also a special case, because they have a `__name__` attribute which the `def` statement sets. Other values do not. In any case, the variable you are using to *reference* the function isn't relevant to the name.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Functions are often defined with names, and debugging tools are allowed to break referential transparency.

Comment: @user253751 Non-functions are also often defined with names. I have nothing against debugging tools breaking referential transparency, but it isn't clear how exactly they should do that. `x = 5; f y = g y + 1; g z = z * 42; print $ f x` You stop inside `g` and want to see the name of `z`. Is it `z`? Is it `y`? Is it `x`? Is it all of the above? Why? How would a debugging tool implement your option of choice?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I don't particularly care - you may as well ask what it should print for the name of `z` when you execute `print $ f (2 + 2)`. Here is how I would implement that in a debugging tool: Every function that is defined with a name (syntax `f x = x + 2` for example, but not `f = \x -> x + 2`) is tagged with its name, source filename and line number. Every other function is tagged with its filename and line number. It is not complicated. Yes, `f . g` would return the location of the definition of `(.)`.

Answer (score 3):

For demonstration purposes, you can try using the [`simple-reflect`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.17/simple-reflect-0.3.3/Debug-SimpleReflect.html) package. It allows some forms of symbolic computation:

```
> foldr f x [1,2,3]
f 1 (f 2 (f 3 x))
> foldl f x [1,2,3]
f (f (f x 1) 2) 3
```

Beware, it has its own limitations. For instance `(f . g) x` won't work unless with suitable type annotations. `[1] ++ x` won't work at all.

Still, if you prepare the examples for a demonstration, you can check them in advance and ensure they work.